# Operation not supported error while PUT to Dynamic CRM Web API

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, dynamics-crm

I'm using the following JS to change the name of an account entity using CRM 2016's Web API:

```
data = JSON.parse('{"name":"<new name>"}');
data = JSON.stringify(data);;

$.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    url: "https://<mySite>.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.0/accounts(<accountId>)",
    data: data,
    contentType: "application/json"
});
```

But my site returns the following error:

```
Message":"Operation not supported on account","ExceptionMessage":"Operation not supported on account","ExceptionType":"Microsoft.Crm.CrmHttpException"
```

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `PUT` request to update a single property, the property name should be appended to the Uri of the entity.

Try this script:

```
data = JSON.parse('{"value":"<new name>"}');
data = JSON.stringify(data);;

$.ajax({
type: "PUT",
url: "https://<mySite>.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.0/accounts(<accountId>)/name",
data: data,
contentType: "application/json"
});
```